# Is it appropriate to perform a t-test on data expressed as T-scores for individual participants?

Tags: t-test, repeated-measures, data-transformation, psychology

I have data that comes as "fully corrected" T-scores (i.e., adjusted for age, sex, SES, etc., to a standardized score with a population mean 50 and SD 10) for 20 participants at time 1 and time 2. How do I figure out if there was a significant change? Can I run a t-test on T-scores?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's "fully corrected t-score? Do you want t-statistics? You want to run t-test on test statistics??

Comment: Please provide full details on exactly how these scores were calculated

Comment: Do you mean what psychologists call T-scores?

Comment: The "fully corrected t-score" comes from being corrected for age, sex, SES, etc. It comes from a cognitive psychological battery that generates the t-scores for me. I have 20 participants who were tested at Time 1 and then again after a treatment was implemented at Time 2. How do I know whether  there was significant change after the treatment?

Answer (score 0):

YES . A linear transformation of data does not change the shape of distribution of original scores. Hence, you can apply t-test on trasformed scores  at time-1 and time-2 in order to ascetain whether  the treatment has produced significant difference  in scores.

Comment: Could you explain in what sense a *corrected* T-score is a "linear transformation of data"?

Comment: I presume that correction for age, sex etc. has to be ignored . The only relevant issue is T-score and not t-score - a wrong connotation for transformed score. I think question should be edited. The OP does not apparently understand that usually we do not correct scores for such variables/ factors. Even the term standardized score is inappropriate.  I should have probably mentioned these notions in the Answer.